# JWplayer multiple player in one page and event handler

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, jwplayer

### Scenario

I have multiple players in the same page. Each instance loads a different video.
I need to handle similar events for every instance.

### Problem

If I just declare the events on a general function – like this `jwplayer().on('play', handler)` – the handler affects only the first player of the page. 
If I declare the player's `id` the console returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: jwplayer("text").on is not a function(anonymous function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create JW Player, you can get an object back and store it in a variable.

```
var myJwPlayerInstance = jwplayer("JWPlayerDiv").setup({ ... });
...
myJwPlayerInstance.on("play", function () { ... });
```

You can do this for each JW Player instance you have, using separate variables or an array.